# .NET MVC - build complex List

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm sorry if I don't quite know how to word this.  I know how I would do this in PHP but not .net MVC.

In short, I need to grab categories from multiple tables.  I know in PHP I would do something like build a new object, then add an array to the object.  For example, I need to be able to build something so I can return it to the view and iterate through it.  So something like:

```
categoryType1 
    subcategoryType1 (also has ID, name, description)
        subsubCategoryType1 (also has ID, name, description)
        subsubCategoryType2 (also has ID, name, description)
        subsubCategoryType3 (also has ID, name, description)
    subcategoryType2 (also has ID, name, description)
        subsubCategoryType1 (also has ID, name, description)
        subsubCategoryType2 (also has ID, name, description)
        subsubCategoryType3 (also has ID, name, description)
categoryType2
    subcategoryType1 (also has ID, name, description)
        subsubCategoryType1 (also has ID, name, description)
        subsubCategoryType2 (also has ID, name, description)
        subsubCategoryType3 (also has ID, name, description)
    subcategoryType2 (also has ID, name, description)
        subsubCategoryType1 (also has ID, name, description)
        subsubCategoryType2 (also has ID, name, description)
        subsubCategoryType3 (also has ID, name, description)
```

Right now, I have one less level, so it looks like this:

In the model:

```
public class LayoutViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> OutcomeType { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller:

```
public PartialViewResult _Sidebar()
    {
        var category1 = db.Category1.Where(oa => oa.Category != "")
            .GroupBy(oa => oa.Category).Select(oa => new LayoutViewModel
            {
                Category = oa.Key,
                Identifier = oa.Key.Replace(" ", "-").ToString(),
                SubCategory = oa.Select(y => y.SubCategory).Distinct()
            });
        return PartialView("_Sidebar", category1);
    }
```

But the above example is only one.  I need to do this multiple times but still return all of them together as one object (list?) to the view.

Comment: So what exactly are you stuck on? Whats the question?

Comment: How can I return the accumulation of multiple queries to the view.  So if I do say a query like var category1, I can add multiple category1 to some other type of variable and return that to the view.  Not sure if this makes sense.

Comment: Just return a `List<T>` or an `array[]` to your view?

Comment: Here's a [Phil Haack article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/), it's pre Razor but the concepts are the same.

Comment: Here's [another question using Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22733003/542251)

Comment: But I'm thinking of something like: ` airports.Add( new Destination() { arrivalName = airport.Add( new subDestination() { arrivalName = airport } ) } );`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not following? What's a `subDestination`?

Comment: I mean basically, just build an object that holds your structure, then send it to the view. Thats it